# Infinite sequence of RV's on finite sample space

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I'm studying probability theory through [these notes](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/reu02/prob.pdf) and I can't quite understand what's being said on page 10 (in relation to the Weak Law of Large Numbers):

> **Remark 4.6**: Strictly speaking, we bent our rules here. An infinite sequence of non-constant, pairwise independent variables requires an infinite sample space.

Just so I understand what is being said: Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is our probability space and $\Omega = \{\omega_1,..,\omega_n\}$ is finite. Is the above statement saying that if $\{\xi_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an infinite sequence of independent RV's on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, then they must all be constants almost surely? I can't quite see why that is the case in general.

Comment: I think not exactly: all *but finitely many* of them will be eventually constant. If the random variables are independent, we need to be able to divide the probabilities an arbitrary number of times. On a finite probability space it's not possible (unless every occurring possibility is either 0 or 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can remove the elements of $\Omega$ which has zero probability. 
Note that, as $\Omega$ is finite, the probability measure $P$ on it *can only take finitely many values*.

Assume $a_i\in\Bbb R$ are in the range of $\xi_i$ (with positive probability), then by independency we have 
$$P\left(\bigwedge_{i\le N}\xi_i=a_i\right)\ =\ \prod_{i\le N}P(\xi_i=a_i)$$
Now if infinitely many of the $\xi_i$'s were nonconstant, it means that $P(\xi_i=a_i)\in (0,1)$ and these products would generate *infinitely many probability values*, contradicting to the above observation.

Thus, we must have only finite many nonconstants among $\xi_i$'s.